# JavaFX-8 ContextMenu in JFXPanel not reacting

Tags: swing, contextmenu, javafx-8

Im working on a legacy SWING application to which i would like to add JavaFX 8 functionality. To integrate JavaFX in SWING i used JFXPanel in a similar fashion as described on this [oracle page](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm).

Everything seems to work just fine except for context menus. Basically i've got one view containing a TableView with a ContextMenu. Clicking one Item from the ContextMenu should trigger doSomething() in my TestController. Here's the FXML file.

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="views.fx.testfx8.TestController">
   <center>
      <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="249.0" text="Foo" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="236.0" text="Bar" />
        </columns>
         <contextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Item 1" onAction="#doSomething"/>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Item 2" onAction="#doSomething"/>
              </items>
            </ContextMenu>
         </contextMenu>
      </TableView>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

My issue is that the popup menu is shown but there are no hover animations and nothing happens if i click an item. However, using the up/down arrow keys and pressing enter works like a charm. The hover animations are showing and the doSomething() method gets invoked.

I found one possible solution [here](http://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/popupmenu-in-javafx/), but it didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a bug report.  JavaFX bug reports should be made in the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: Were you able to resolve/workaround this bug? We are seeing the same issue with all popups(from combobox, right clicks, menus) once we tried to run with jre 8 on SLES 11 SP 1).

Answer (score 1):

This bug will be fixed in jre 8 update 20.

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36956

I have tested this issue with the early release candidate and it does fix the bug.